# Activities listening for events in EventBus

Tags: android, android-activity, asynchronous, android-lifecycle, greenrobot-eventbus

I have got an activity with the view of an object received from an async HTTP request. I am using EventBus to post an event with the object and in the activity the following method:

```
public void onEventMainThread(MyObjectEvent event) {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    showMyObject(event.getMyObject());
}
```

Previously, I have registered the activity's instance in its onCreate() method:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

I am aware of the Activity lifecycle in Android and I think that my way to use EventBus is not right because I am registering an instance which could be destroyed by Android. I am not keen on registering an instance with such behaviour.

I could register an Application instance or an object with every onEvent() method but I would be coding a God object.

Would be a solution use sticky events by verifying getStickyEvent(MyObjectEvent) is null and then register the activity? In case of getting not null I would register the activity.

I would like to know what is the best approach to use EventBus with views in Android. 
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you register in onCreate, please think about unregistering in onDestroy.

Also, please have a look at registerSticky, which immediately delivers an event if available.

Comment: Is registering an activity recommendable?

Comment: It common practice to register activities (and fragments) using their life cycle methods.